# ACF Filed show anywhere?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

hoping to get a bit of direction here.

I have an ACF Field Group assigned to show on a Insights CPT.

Obviously the location rules control which editor it shows in, in this case it shows If post type is equal to Insights and Post Template is equal to Video.

This works well when adding my custom code to insights_video.php

```
$playtime = $content['play_time'];
<p class="dashicons-before dashicons-clock"> <?= $playtime ?> mins</p>
```

Very simple and works well !

My problem is when i try to add the code to the Insights Archive page within the loop, nothing happens

```
<?php if ($insights->have_posts()) :
                while ($insights->have_posts()) : $insights->the_post(); 
                    $topics = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'topic');
                    $images = get_field('images');
                    $playtime = $content['play_time'];
                    $content = get_field('content'); ?>
                    <div class="tst-content-tile">
                        <a href="<?= get_permalink() ?>" class="tst-content-tile__image">
                            <div class="tst-content-tile__image-inside" style="background-image: url(<?= $images['preview_image']['sizes']['large'] ?>)"></div>
                            <div class="tst-content-tile__image-overlay">
                                <div class="tst-content-tile__image-overlay-blue"></div>
                                <img src="<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/assets/images/content-tile-link-arrow.svg" class="tst-content-tile__image-overlay-arrow">
                            </div>
                        </a>

                        <div class="tst-content-tile__tags-container">
                            <?php if($topics): ?>
                                <?php foreach($topics as $topic): ?>
                                    <div class="tst-content-tile__tag"><?= $topic->name ?></div>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        
                        <h5><?= get_the_title() ?></h5><p class="dashicons-before dashicons-clock"> <?= $playtime ?> mins</p>

                        <p><?= $content['summary'] ?></p>

                        <a href="<?= get_permalink() ?>" class="tst-button">Read more</a>
                        
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any direction would be great .. many thanks

Comment: Hi, have you tried to explicitly add the current post id as the second paramater (in the loop), when calling 'get_field('content')' ?

Comment: Dexter i haven't because there isn't a specific post ID, this is the post archive template so it would be presenting all posts not a specific one. Unless i'm misunderstanding you my friend.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, let me rephrase it : try to call get_field(), from inside the loop, with $post->ID as the second parameter : since you are in a loop, sometimes ACF can be confused, I find out that calling the get_field with the second parameter can fix it. it would look like so: get_field('content', $post->ID)  (assuming 'content' is the name of the acf field you want to retrive the value from).

Comment: I see what you mean but i'm struggling to write it correctly ... the field is actually called by $playtime = $content['play_time'];  .. where $content is the name of the group within the field group and play_time is the text field .. does that make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write a complete answer as comment is pretty limited :/

There is an error in your code.

This can't work:

```
...
$playtime = $content['play_time'];
$content = get_field('content');
...
```

Because you ask PHP to affect the value of key 'play_time' from the array $content BEFORE you affect any value to $content.

You should invert those two lines :

```
...
$content = get_field('content');
$playtime = $content['play_time'];
...
```

THis way PHP know the value affected to the variable $content.

Comment: I know feel rather foolish .. it was in plain sight !! Thank you so much for your time and patience !!

Comment: You're welcome, it happended to all of us ;)